# Redirect to a directory and hide url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The directive below will redirect all non www subdomain to www subdomain. For example:
`blog.myname.com` will redirect to `www.blog.myname.com`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www)[^\.]*)\.myname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%1.myname.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I will be more precise. In my root directory I create a directory call blog so the directory structure is now like this `myname.com/blog`.

This is what I need when user visiting my page:

1. If the URL is `myname.com` or `www.myname.com` -> User will see index file at root directory. No change.
2. If the URL is `hello.myname.com` -> it will add www so it will become like this `www.hello.myname.com` and redirected to `www.hello.myname.com`
3. If URL is `www.hello.myname.com` -> User is redirected to `myname.com/blog` and can see content in `myname.com/blog` BUT the URL is masked and still show `www.hello.myname.com`

The reason for this is you can test `ipohla.cheapantivirus.me` and you can see index file at `myname.com/blog` but if `www.ipohla.cheapantivirus.me` the domain is propagate correctly. That's why I need to add www to non www subdomain. Thank you.

My current .htacess below `www.subdomain.myname.com` will not be externally redirected and see content of `myname.com/blog/index.html` directory.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# externally redirect all subdomains to www.subdomain...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www)[^\.]*)\.cheapantivirus\.me$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%1.cheapantivirus.me%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Proxy to www.cheapantivirus.com/blog/index.html for every subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?((?!www)[^\.]*)\.cheapantivirus\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.cheapantivirus.com/blog/index.html [P,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a generic rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?((?!www)[^\.]*)\.cheapantivirus\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.cheapantivirus.com/blog/index.html [P,L]
```

Note that this requires mod_proxy enabled in your Apache.

This will proxy:

```
www.blog.cheapantivirus.com to www.cheapantivirus.com/blog/index.html
www.blog.cheapantivirus.com to www.cheapantivirus.com/blog/index.html
www.subdomain.cheapantivirus.com to www.cheapantivirus.com/blog/index.html
www.foo.cheapantivirus.com to www.cheapantivirus.com/blog/index.html
```

Since it is using `P` flag therefore it won't cause your browser URL to change.

Answer (score 0):

> How could I redirect user to www.blog.myname.com/blog/index.html but URL at the address bar is masked and only showing www.blog.myname.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blog\.myname\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ blog/index.html [L]
```

If you want to send all requests from www.blog.myname.com to www.blog.myname.com/blog use this instead

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blog\.myname\.com$ [NC] 
#not already /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/blog/[NC] 
#not an existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ blog%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Add the following to the `.htaccess` file after the redirect rule you already have

Comment: I have wasted your time by asking broad question. I'm really sorry...